# My div keeps getting echoed outside of its parent

Tags: php, html

I have this div, which runs some php and then passes one of three sets of parameters to a function. The function returns an echoed div. For some reason, this div is appearing below the parent instead of inside it. It seems pretty straightforward, which is why it's causing me so much trouble. What am I missing?

This is the parent div:

```html
<div class='panel-body' hrid='<?php echo $homeroom['homeroom_id'] ?>'>
    <!-- figure out $class, $lunchroom, and $order for each div containing student -->
    <?php 
    $students = get('student', ['homeroom_id' => $homeroom['homeroom_id']], 'student_id', '', 'API')->fetchAll();
    foreach($students as $student){
        $class='';
        $dest = '';
        if(in_array($student['student_id'], $detentionIds)){
            echo returnStudent('detention', $firstRoundDetention, $homeroom, $notUsed, $student, 1);                            
        }elseif(in_array($student['student_id'], $hwIds)){
            echo returnStudent('homework-club', $firstRoundHC, $homeroom, $notUsed, $student, 2);
        }else{
            echo returnStudent('recess', $firstRoundRecess, $homeroom, $notUsed, $student, 3);
        } 
    } ?>  
</div>
```

And this is the function that generates the div to be echoed inside the parent:

```html
function returnStudent($class, $array, $homeroom, $notUsed, $student, $dataSort){
    if($homeroom['homeroom_id'] == $array['room1']){
        $class.= ' not-moved';
        $dest = $array['room1'];
        $suffix = 'homeroom matches room1';
    }else{
        if(in_array($homeroom['homeroom_id'], $array['rooms'])){
            $class.= ' moved';
            $dest = $array['room1'];
            $hr = get('homeroom', ['homeroom_id' => $array['room1']], 'homeroom_id', 1, 'API')->fetch();
            $suffix = $hr['homeroom_name'];
        }else{
            if($notUsed['homeroom_id'] == $homeroom['homeroom_id']){
                $class.= ' not-moved';
                $dest =  $homeroom['homeroom_id'];
                $suffix = 'does not move';
            }else{
                $class.= ' moved';
                $dest = $notUsed['homeroom_id'];
                $hr = get('homeroom', ['homeroom_id' => $notUsed['homeroom_id']], 'homeroom_id', 1, 'API')->fetch();
                $suffix = $hr['homeroom_name'];
            }
        }
    } 
 return "<div 
    class='alert student " . $class ."' 
    destination = '" . strtolower($dest) ."'
    data-sort = '" . $dataSort . "' 
    studentid='" . $student['student_id'] ."'
    homeroomid = '" . $student['homeroom_id'] . "'>

    " . $student['student_fname'] . " " . $student['student_lname'] . " - " . $suffix ."

    <!-- close student div -->
    </div>";
}
```

Comment: have you checked the generated html? Are they *physicaly* outside of the parent div, or are they just *appearing* outside the parent div? In the later case you might have some css-style attributes causing this.

Comment: Post the resulting HTML

Comment: Yes they are literally outside the parent div. <div class='panel-body'></div> and then around 92 divs appear immediately below it.

Comment: Wow. I was completely wrong. I was using inspect element, and the divs weren't appearing to be nested inside the parent (if I clicked the dropdown for the parent, nothing was inside, and all the divs were appearing below it). When I actually viewed the source code, everything was where it should be. But that still doesn't solve the problem I'm having with my jquery, which is what I thought was going on... now I'm more confused than before.

Comment: what problem are you having with your jquery then? may you edit your question?